# How to deal with the column data in the RCFile using Spark Java.‏

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to use Spark Java to read RCFile. I find the functions via searching on Google, they told me to use the hadoopFile function. I write this:

```
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext("local", "Accumulate",System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), JavaSparkContext.jarOfClass(spark.wendy.RCFileAccumulate.class));

JavaPairRDD<String,Array> idListData = ctx.hadoopFile("/rcfinancetest",RCFileInputFormat.class,String.class, String.class);

idListData.saveAsTextFile("/financeout");
```

Then I open the result file, the result is as followed:

```
(0,org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.columnar.BytesRefArrayWritable@4442459f)
(1,org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.columnar.BytesRefArrayWritable@4442459f)
(2,org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.columnar.BytesRefArrayWritable@4442459f)
(3,org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.columnar.BytesRefArrayWritable@4442459f)
(4,org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.columnar.BytesRefArrayWritable@4442459f)
```

The second phase of all record is the same. How can I deal with the variable? How to deal with the column data in the RCFile?By the way, I create the RCFile via Hive. I think it has nothing to do with the spark reading program. Could you help me ?

Comment: Have proper title it helps in getting better user attention

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask